# How to zip a file named "-"

Tags: linux

I can unzip a zip file contains a file named "-"

But it seems that "-" is a magic char in zip command...

How could I zip this file with zip command?

Comment: Escaping it might work ( \- ), although there are lots of other good examples below.

Comment: Using \- will only work if the program itself supports it: this is more than likely **not** the case and will not do what you want

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `zip ./-`

`-` means: read from stdin (standard input)

Comment: +1, but I don't think it's an alias for `stdin` in case of `zip`.

Comment: ok, could also be the beginning of an option like -f or something. i don’t have a linux machine at hand to test/verify. nevertheless, the question was how to zip this file, not why it was not working :)

Comment: Sure, that's why +1 ;-)

Comment: :)

Comment: Careful with the word "alias" because there is a shell construct of that name. Using `-` to mean "read from the standard input" is a common unix command-line argument idiom, but it is *not* translated as such by the shell.

Comment: edited answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

On my Uni profesor said when we have strange name of file we should use all path to file ;) 
example:

```
~/-

/home/mariusz/Desktop/-
```

Answer (score 0):

@knittl's answer should work, but I think the more correct answer is:

```
zip ... -- -
```

Where the plain `--` says that the rest of the input is filenames. Most linux commands support this, but I'm not sure off the top of my head if zip does or not.

Comment: I also thought so and wanted to give an answer like this, but I've tried it with `zip` and it didn't work. IIRC, zip has its own processing of options and doesn't use `getopt`.

Comment: For shame. Oh well, this will probably be useful to someone else trying to use a different command, so I'll leave it here anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it's somewhat funny that both you and knittl made some perfectly sensible assumptions that just do not apply to `zip`.

Comment: The "--" option is accepted by many GNU utilities and some others on some platforms.  However, it is NOT the recommended method.  Prefixing -* filenames with a relative or absolute path, canonically using ./-* is most portable answer.

I consider it to be the most basic technical screening question for such hands-on sysadmin positions.  (Only partial credit for -- answers, full credit for ./, and extra for laughing and pointing out that it's an old FAQ --- 0 pts. for any attempt at quoting or escaping with backslash; those are DANGEROUS)!